# Get Data from a single table to an empty table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am quite new to SQL. I couldn't find solution and I want your expertise here.

I have one table "boxes" and contains the color and type and condition. I want to get the number of types per color WHERE Condition = 'NEW'. Thanks in advance :)

My tale looks like that:

```
           Boxes

    COLOR  TYPE  CONDITION   
    red     x        NEW
    green   y        NEW
    green   x        NEW
    blue    c        OLD
    red     b        OLD
    red     a        OLD
```

I want to put the data from here into another table called "ColorPerType"

expected output:

```
      ColorPerType

    Color  NumberOfTypes
    red        1
    green      2
    blue       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [`SELECT...INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement if `ColorPerType` does not exist:

```
select 
  color,
  sum(case when condition = 'new' then 1 else 0 end) as NumberOfTypes
into ColorPerType  
from boxes
group by color
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d088dfde18480aebc5f8ce127c7cd520).
If the table `ColorPerType` already exists use this:

```
insert into ColorPerType (color, NumberOfTypes)
select 
  color,
  sum(case when condition = 'new' then 1 else 0 end) as NumberOfTypes
from boxes
group by color
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c1af138306d136f7c51cbae1403d8f4).

Results:
`ColorPerType` table

```
> color | NumberOfTypes
> :---- | ------------:
> blue  |             0
> green |             2
> red   |             1
```

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much. I just want to clarify something. 

if I want to add more selections ( for example add one more column in the ColorPerType Table) and include there a YES/NO condition if it is Red. Assuming the column already exists, will I just add one more case? or make it separately?

Answer (score 1):

You want aggregation with `case` expression :

```
select color,
       sum(case when condition = 'new' then 1 else 0 end) as NumberOfTypes
from boxes b
group by color;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to count a Type only once this would work;

```
SELECT 
color,
SUM(DISTINCT TYPE) as NumberOfTypes
FROM boxes 
GROUP BY color HAVING condition = 'NEW';
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends, when you say you need a new table, do you want this table to update when new data goes in the original table? If so, you need a view not a table.

`CREATE VIEW ColourPerType AS 
SELECT b.Color, COUNT(b.Type)
FROM Boxes b
WHERE b.Condition = 'NEW'
GROUP BY b.Color`